# ASP.NET Add Hyperlink for whole row of Datatable/Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, datatable, hyperlink

I'm generating a DataTable with some data and using it as DataSource for a GridView that will be added to an ASP.NET-Webpage.

```
GridView gvItems = new GridView();
DataTable dtItems = new DataTable();

dtItems.Columns.Add("name");
dtItems.Columns.Add("description");
dtItems.Columns.Add("count");

foreach(var item in items)
{
    string name = item.name;
    string description = item.description;
    string count = item.count.ToString();
    string link = "~/Views/Items.aspx?item=" + item.name;
    string linkName = item.name;

    dtItems.Rows.Add(name, description, count)
}

gvItems.DataSource = dtItems;
gvItems.DataBind();

PlaceHolder.Controls.Add(gvItems)
```

Is it possible to generate a Hyperlink for each whole row that is added?
I want a detailed page of an item to be opened if someone clicks somewhere inside of a row.

Comment: Do a Google search for Gridview Master / Details.

Comment: doesn't help, thats why I'm asking

Comment: Rather than a whole row being a link, you would typically make the description field in this example, be the link. It gets messier when you create these in code rather than markup. Still doable.

Comment: so if i understand aright it is doable but only with a more complicated method that don't really make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot add a link to an entire row directly, but you can do it with an attribute and some jQuery. For that you need the `RowDataBound` event. But since you are creating a GridView dynamically you need to add it with code.

```
gvItems.RowDataBound += GvItems_RowDataBound;
gvItems.DataSource = dtItems;
gvItems.DataBind();
```

Then the RowDataBound method itself.

```
private void GvItems_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    //check if the row is a datarow
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        //cast the row back to a datarowview
        DataRowView row = e.Row.DataItem as DataRowView;

        //add the url as an attribute to the row
        e.Row.Attributes.Add("data-url", row["link"].ToString());

        //give the row a class to the jquery click event can be bound to it
        e.Row.Attributes.Add("class", "ClickableRow");
    }
}
```

Then for some front end code to handle the click.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".ClickableRow").click(function () {
            location.href = $(this).data("url");
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Sorry for the very, very late response! 
Thank you very much, that's exactly the kind solution I looked for!

Comment: Btw: is it possible to add these attributes to the rows in a different way without this event?

Comment: Only if you put the url in some (hidden) font-end element such as a div or a span and the also add it to the row as a data-url with jquery.

Comment: Ok, but in this case I think I already got the right solution. Thanks again!